# Image Preview not displayed

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a form for uploading an image and displaying a small preview of the image after selecting it. The preview is failing to display.

HTML code:

```
<label for="">Image</label>
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="image" id="img">
<img src="#" id="imgPreview" alt="">
```

JS code:

```
function readURL(input) {
        if(input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                $("#imgPreview").attr('src', e.target.result).width(100).height(100);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
        $("#img").change(function() {
            readURL(this);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Your handler for the change event is packed up inside your function, so never executed. Put it outside of it.

Comment: You are calling your `readURL` function inside that function. Move that out to see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your change function on `#img` is never called because it inside your `readURL` function. You just need to put change function outside and everything good to go.

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $("#imgPreview")
                .attr("src", e.target.result)
                .width(100)
                .height(100);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#img").change(function() {
    readURL(this);
});
```

Working demo [here](https://codepen.io/khanhvdv/pen/ZrYNEK)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put change event of #img in the page init.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <label for="">Image</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image" id="img">
    <img src="#" id="imgPreview" alt="">
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#img').change(function () {
                readURL(this);
            });
        })
        function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $("#imgPreview").attr('src', e.target.result).width(100).height(100);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```